# Finite Field has Finite Characteristic

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, finite-fields

I want to prove that for finite $\mathbb{F}$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that
$$ \underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{\text{n times}} = 0 $$

Proof: by the field axioms, there exists $1\in\mathbb{F}$. Also, by closure, $1+1\in\mathbb{F}$. We can continue this and construct a set $X = \{1,1+1,1+1+1,...\}$. Since $\mathbb{F}$ is finite, let $|\mathbb{F}|=k$. We construct $X$ so that it has $k+1$ elements. Then, by pigeonhole principle, there must exist $l,m\in\mathbb{F}$ such that
$$ l = \underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{\text{a times}}=\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{\text{b times}} = m $$
WLOG $a>b$. Then
$$ \underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{\text{a-b times}}=0 $$
which is the result of the theorem.

I'm sure this is valid but I'd like to check. Any suggestions/errors?

Comment: Looks ok to me, More formally, show that the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{F}$ given by $n \mapsto n \cdot 1$ (where $n\cdot 1$ is the $n$-th multiple of the identity $1 \in \mathbb{F}$) is a homomorphism of additive groups (actually of rings), and it has to have a non-trivial kernel.